# blue/green deployment in case of event drivern approach

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-build, blue-green-deployment

We have few services in our GCP cloud environment which are consuming and publishing messages from pubsub and does not have any http api. When we deploy our services via pipeline, we use green/blue deployment stretagy with traffic configuration is 100% to green revision.

We observed that after the deployment one revision(latest one) with tag **green** and old revision with **blue** tag.

What our concern is that during testing we observed that some of our pubsub messages are getting consumed by blue revision, but it should have been consumed by only green revision.
Afer some research, I found that 100% traffic is for http calls not for events(pubsub).

Can someone please suggest what could be the solution here so that latest green revision consumes all the messages from pubsub.

Comment: you case is very interesting but it requires more details. Can you share more? Where are deployed your services? How the revision and traffic management is done? What's the number of message per seconds? Do you observe this behavior for minutes or for hours/days?

Comment: We are using GCP CloudRun where we deploy our services using tekton pipelines. We always set traffic to 100% to the green revision after successful deployment via pipeline itself. We observed it for few messages(~8-10) only one day. Then for as a temporary solution, we manually deleted blue revisions from CloudRun.

Comment: Do you use push subscription? Eventarc? Are you sure that the 8-10 messages are sent AFTER the deployment and the new traffic routing?

Comment: We use Pull subscription and yes around 8 to 10 messages are consumed by blue revision after the deployment.

Comment: Pull? how did you implemented it? What's trigger your cloud run to pull your messages? Do you use Cloud Run jobs (you shouldn't, there is no tags and traffic routing)?